# On duplicate key update throws an en duplicate entry exception

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table with the following structure

```
create table stats
(
    id             int auto_increment primary key,
    serial_no      varchar(20) not null,
    epoch          int         not null,
    version        varchar(20) null,
    
    constraint idx_serial_no unique (serial_no)
);
```

And I run the following update query

```
INSERT INTO stats 
       (serial_no, version, epoch)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE id        = LAST_INSERT_ID(id),
       serial_no = VALUES(serial_no),
       version   = VALUES(version),
       epoch     = VALUES(epoch)
```

Oddly enough, at one point MySQL 5.7 stopped updating the data and instead started sending me `Duplicate entry 'abc123' for key 'idx_serial_no'`, when I execute the query above.

Comment: I tested this here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7njfSHA8tNzdNntF5hBLwt/0 but did not get an error. Is it possible you have a trigger? Or another INSERT statement ran without an ON DUPLICATE KEY clause?

Answer (score 0):

You have two unique keys -- `PRIMARY KEY(id)` and `UNIQUE(serial_no)`.  Furthermore, the IODKU is specifying both `id` and `serial_no`.  Apparently, both values are in the table, but in different rows!

"Normally" one would not include the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column (id) when doing IODKU.

Why even have `id`?  Why not use `PRIMARY KEY(serial_no)`?